# SQL Query to replace part of HTML (iframe src="http:// to iframe src="://)

Tags: mysql, sql, joomla2.5

I have a Joomla 2.5.28 that is now using `https` instead of `http`.

Some articles (many) contain embeded videos from Vimeo.

Originally, those videos were embeded using http, so now I have in my database in fields `introtext` or `fulltext`, html code like:

```
<p>Text, etc...</p>
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/123" width="690" height="518" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
<iframe width="690" height="400" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="https://skydrive.live.com/embed?cid=xxx></iframe>
<ul>
<li>
...
```

So, how do I build a SQL query to keep the HTML as it is but replace:

```
<iframe src="http://
```

To:

```
<iframe src="://
```

Comment: I would advice you update your database (rewriting the fields) rather than try to modify select query as you may find that the performance hit is considerable.

Comment: It should be `//...` instead of `://...` I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `replace` function

```
mysql> select replace('<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/123"','<iframe src="http://','<iframe src="://') as replaced ;
+---------------------------------------------+
| replaced                                    |
+---------------------------------------------+
| <iframe src="://player.vimeo.com/video/123" |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

So using above you can write the update command as

```
update table_name
set field_name = replace(field_name,'<iframe src="http://','<iframe src="://');
```

You can do the same while selecting as well

```
select
replace(field_name,'<iframe src="http://','<iframe src="://') as field_name
from table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

See mysql [REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function:

```
SELECT REPLACE('<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/123" width="690" height="518" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>', '<iframe src="http://', '<iframe src="://');
```